# How to load a ramdisk now?

Tags: 16.04, kernel, initrd

latest kernels have made ramdisk modules:

CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM=m

Which is the module and where to find it.

Is loadable during boot from initramfs ?

I had root on software RAID1 with SSD and Ramdisk (/dev/ram1)

with write-mostly on SSD.

CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM in original kernel is boolean, now is module ?!?!

Any rationale for this change ?

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block ramdisk module is called `brd` and can be loaded as follows:

```
sudo modprobe brd rd_size=100000
```

where `rd_size` is the number of blocks. After this step you have a device `/dev/ram0` that you can put a filesystem on:

```
sudo mkfs /dev/ram0
```

and mount.

Comment: Thank You ! I've added "brd rd_size=16777216" to /etc/initramfs/modules . Run update-initramfs -u after and everything is ok !

Comment: Good. If you are satisfied with my answer, please tick the check mark next to it to mark your question as answered.

Comment: I read in the `mkfs` man page that if you don't specify `--type` ext2 is used by default. When comes to a RAM disk, I wonder if ext4 would be better or not.

Answer (score 1):

Another option for a RAM Disks is [zram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram). When you place a file onto a zram RAM disk, the file gets quickly compressed during the transfer and it is transparently decompress during the retrieval. This can be helpful in circumstances where your system doesn't quite have the amount of RAM you desire for your RAM disk.

Here's how to create a zram RAM disk:

Make a folder to which you will mount your RAM disk:

```
sudo mkdir /tmp/ramdisk
```

Change the ownership of that folder, so your user will have full access to the RAM disk when we later mount it:

```
sudo chown -R yourUserName:yourGroupName /tmp/ramdisk
```

Make the folder immutable so you don't ever accidentally fill up your  OS partition with data intended for the RAM disk:

```
sudo chattr +i /tmp/ramdisk
```

Load the zram module:

```
sudo modprobe zram
```

Create a 1GB ram disk:

```
sudo zramctl --find --size 1G
```

The command above will output the device path of the RAM disk you've created. It will most likely be `/dev/zram0`, and that's what we'll assume going forward.

Format the RAM disk to EXT4:

```
sudo mke2fs -t ext4 -O ^has_journal -L "zram device" /dev/zram0
```

Mount the RAM disk to the immutable mount point folder we created:

```
sudo mount /dev/zram0 /tmp/ramdisk
```

Now you should be able to move files to and from the RAM disk located at `/tmp/ramdisk/`.

If you're done playing with it, unmount it:

```
sudo umount /tmp/ramdisk/
```

Lastly, lets destroy the RAM disk and free up any memory it was using:

```
sudo zramctl --reset /dev/zram0
```

If you also want to remove the the folder `/tmp/ramdisk`, first make it mutable:

```
sudo chattr -i /tmp/ramdisk
```

Now you can delete the folder:

```
rm -rf /tmp/ramdisk
```